# where.not() not working on arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have an array called user_ids and I want to select the records whose user_ids are not in the array.

Here is what I used:

```
MyModel.where.not(user_id: user_ids)
```

But I got `Error wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`.

Same thing happens when I used `MyModel.where.not('user_id=?', user_ids).` I thought maybe it was becuase the array was empty, but same thing happens with arrays that are not empty.

Does anybody know why it happens?

I am using Rails 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
MyModel.where('user_id not in (?)', user_ids)
```

Comment: yep I tried this but do you know why where.not() does not work?

Comment: I havn't heard much about .where.not() but i guess :
it can't take array of ids. it may work with single id like '!=' operator.

try passing a single id, instead of array

Comment: @Lee7355512727 What's your database? If you're using MongoDB (and mongoid) you can do that like: `Model.nin(url: ['', nil])` or `Model.where(:url.ne => "", :url.exists => true)`